# make parent with no height set get children's height and not grandparent height

Tags: html, css

I have a container inside a container which has some elements inside of it.
I want the parent container to not get grandparent height but get the children's height.

my code: https://jsfiddle.net/grLx7zoq/

To clarify, I want `payment-customer-container` to not get parent height but have the height of its children.

Comment: not sure, but I think using `height:auto;` I will try in vscode if yes I will answer

Comment: @LaaouatniAnas I have tried using `height: auto` on `payment-customer-container` but it did not change anything.

Comment: ok. I will try on vscode and see if I can find a solution... however maybe someone with more experience can find the solution before me, here there is an amazing community... let see (I will try to do my best)

Comment: yes I found the bug

Comment: in devtools when adding `height: auto` works, so I thinking about this... so I copy the name of the selector (only name) that makes it works and use CTRL+F shortcut on vscode, I found you write 2 times the same selector... before founding this information I write the `height: auto;` in the first but the second has `80vh` now deleting the `height:80vh` from the 2nd and putting `height: auto` works!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have 2 selectors with the functionality...

when changing the first doesn't change the second selector

```css
.payment-customer-container { 
   height: auto;
}

....

.payment-customer-container {
   height: 80vh; /* the browser choose the last */
}
```

useful documentations:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

> Specificity is the means by which browsers decide which CSS property values are the most relevant to an element and, therefore, will be applied. Specificity is based on the matching rules which are composed of different sorts of CSS selectors.

```css
.payment-customer-container {
  width: 40vw;
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: hsl(0, 0%, 97%);
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  margin-left: 30vw;
  margin-top: 8.5vh;
  /* deleted margin: 80vh -> TO BECOME auto*/
  height: auto;
  /*align and justify don't work without display, so I putted it*/
  /*personally I prefer grid or flex-direction: column;*/
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.payment-customer-header {
  font-family: 'Heebo-Regular';
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  text-align: center;
}

.payment-customer-body {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 5vh;
}

.payment-customer-input-container {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  margin-top: 3vh;
  align-items: center;
}

.payment-customer-label {
  flex: 2;
  padding: 1rem;
  font-family: 'heebo-light';
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  text-align: right;
  direction: rtl;
}

.payment-customer-input {
  flex: 3;
  direction: rtl;
  text-align: right;
  height: 4vh;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #888;
  background-color: hsl(0, 0%, 97%);
}

.payment-customer-input:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.payment-customer-input::placeholder {
  font-family: 'heebo-light';
}

.payment-customer-input:-ms-input-placeholder {
  font-family: 'heebo-light';
}

.payment-customer::-ms-input-placeholder {
  font-family: 'heebo-light';
}

.payment-customer-input::-moz-placeholder {
  font-family: 'heebo-light';
}

.payment-customer-city-results-container {
  flex: 3;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.payment-customer-city-result {
  height: 5vh;
  line-height: calc(5vh - 1rem);
  background-color: white;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  margin-top: 10px;
  text-align: right;
  font-family: 'heebo-light';
  font-size: 1rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.payment-customer-city-result-chevron {
  position: absolute;
  left: 2vw;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="payment-container">
    <!-- form -->
    <form action="/payment" method="post">
      <!-- GrandParent -->
      <div class="payment-customer-container fadeInBottom" id="payment-customer-container-address">
        <!-- 1 -->
        <div class="payment-customer-header">test1</div>

        <!-- parent -->
        <div class="payment-customer-body">

          <!-- 1st child -->
          <div class="payment-customer-input-container">
            <!-- 2 -->
            <label class="payment-customer-label">test2:</label>

            <!-- select -->
            <select class="payment-customer-input" id="payment-customer-select-city" name="payment-customer-select-city">
              <option value="" disabled selected>test</option>
              <!-- 3 -->
              <option value="test">test3</option>
              <!-- 4 -->
              <option value="test">test4</option>
              <!-- 5 -->
              <option value="test">test5</option>
            </select>
          </div>

          <!-- 2nd child -->
          <div class="payment-customer-input-container">
            <!-- 6 -->
            <label class="payment-customer-label">test6:</label>
            <!-- input -->
            <input type="text" class="payment-customer-input" placeholder="test" id="customer-address" name="customer-address" />
          </div>

          <!-- 3rd child -->
          <div class="payment-customer-input-container" style="margin-top: 0.5vh;">
            <!-- 7 -->
            <label class="payment-customer-label">test7</label>

            <div class="payment-customer-city-results-container">
              <div class="payment-customer-city-result">
                <span class="payment-customer-city-result-chevron"><i class="fas fa-chevron-left"></i></span>
                <span>test8</span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>

    </form>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Did not see that. I was intending that the second selector will be `payment-container` and accidentally typed the first selector.